# Swap fixed element based on z-index and layering

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop a CSS effect where there is a fixed colored element in the top / left corner of a webpage. There are different "stages" / chunks of background (red, green, blue) with 1000px height. At each bridge between stages I would like for the color of the icon to transition. I mocked something up on jsfiddle. I literally want to see two halfs of the two fixed elements overlapping to make one, that would make me so happy.

http://jsfiddle.net/reggi/vxBV3/

Here's the CSS

```
.stage{width:100%;height:1000px;position:relative;}

.stage.one{background:red;z-index:1;}
.stage.two{background:green;z-index:1;}
.stage.three{background:blue;z-index:1;}

.box{width:50px;height:50px;position:fixed;margin:10px;}

.box.one{background:purple;z-index:1;}
.box.two{background:orange;z-index:1;}
.box.three{background:yellow;z-index:1;}
```

​And the HTML

```
<!--

<div class="box one"></div>

<div class="box two"></div>

<div class="box three"></div>

-->

<div class="stage one">
    <div class="box one"></div>
</div>

<div class="stage two">
    <div class="box two"></div>
</div>

<div class="stage three">
    <div class="box three"></div>
</div>​
```

I would like this to be **CSS ONLY**! I know that javascript would make this easier but I would like to push the limits of CSS if possible.

Comment: After playing around with this, I'm starting to believe that it's impossible.

Comment: CSS has no way of interacting with where the screen is scrolled without the help of javascript, can't see this happening in CSS alone.

Comment: @RickCalder I would disagree. CSS position is directly tied to scrolling, the where comes in where the elements start and end, and what's hidden in-front of and behind them.

Comment: No, CSS position is directly tied to an element and it's position in relation to the screen when rendered, not on movement. Two entirely different things. The browser itself can react to things like percentages but there is no ability in CSS for if style conditionals. So there is no way to say if this element touches that element, or if the screen moves to this y position.

Comment: @RickCalder I get you, but it doesn't have to be event-based. Checkout this lastest [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reggi/vxBV3/3/) to so my progress. I'm talking pure illusionary css.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing as the first one you posted in Chrome. The green comes up and covers the red and the purple box, nothing else happens? Are you viewing this in a different browser?

Comment: lol now you got me thinking about it, the only way I really see it working so far is using opacities and layers, it's not exactly what you want but I think it's getting close: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/vxBV3/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/soneleqifi/1/edit?html,css,output)

This is impossible to do with CSS alone, here's why. When You set the first elements `.stage.one` (red), `.stage.two`(green) and `.box.one`(purple), your setting them all up to work so that the purple box is on top of the red and goes under the green. At this point your stuck, there's no way to put another box over purple, under red, and over green. It's impossible.

[image]